# Where does browser-solidity store .sol files?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I've got a local instance of browser-solidity running with a bunch of .sol files open. Does anyone know where those source files are stored (on Mac OSX)? I can't find them anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser-solidity stores the .sol files in the browser's local storage.

If you would like to view them you can view them:

- Chrome via `Developer tools > Application > Storage > Local storage`
- Firefox via `Tools > Web Developer > Storage Inspector` (You may need to enable the storage tool in [Firefox's Developer Settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Settings))